# Draft10 websocket aggregating two client messages into one message on nodejs

Tags: websocket

I'm having a problem with draft10 websockets in chrome 14+.  When two messages get sent from the client very quickly in succession, they end up as one message on my nodejs sever instance (using https with upgrade).

I am trying to make my own websocket server that supports both 75/76 and 10.  I can demask messages when sent in isolation from 10, but when sent together the masking is off on the second message.

Are websockets draft10 known to combine messages sent in quick succession?  Or is this an anomaly?

Is there a special character that is sent when the messages are combined into one such that you can parse them out and reset the mask/frame?

Comment: Well, you do know the length of each frame because that's sent along. You can use that to your advantage by knowing where the first frame ends (i.e. where the second frame starts).

Comment: If you actually mean your nodejs code gets a single buffer containing two frames, see above. Otherwise, your question doesn't make much sense. In any case, you should distinguish between the buffer your server gets, the messages, and the frames. Messages may be sent over multiple frames, read the spec for more info.